# How to compare a list of constants to a list of variables

Tags: prolog

The predicate needs to compare two lists (one of variables, one of constants) like this :

```
?- test([A,B,B],[1,2,3]).
false.

?- test([A,B,B],[1,2,2]).
true.

?- test([A,B,C],[1,2,2]).
false.
```

First i associate each variable to its constant with this predicate :

```
set([],[]).
set([X],[Y]):-X is Y.
set([H1|T1],[H2|T2]):-H1 is H2, set(T1,T2).
```

It works for the first two exemples above however it doesn't write "true". Also it doesn't work for the third one :

```
?- set([A,B,C],[1,2,2]).
A = 1,
B = C, C = 2
```

How do can I modify this predicate so it checks if T1 was already used and in that case if it was associated to a different variable (and therefore return false)?

Comment: Can you explain *why* the 3rd one is wrong?  If the same variable is used in different positions, those positions have to have the same value; but why can't different variables happen to have the same value?

Comment: @ScottHunter: based on how I understand it, there is an implicit "all different" constraint over the list of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [**`dif/2`** constraint](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=dif/2) between every two different variables variables.

We can obtain the list of variables with [**`term_variables/2`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=term_variables/2), and then we can for example design a predicate `all_diff/1` that applies `dif` between every two different variables by making use of [**`maplist/2`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/2), like:

```
all_diff([]).
all_diff([H|T]) :-
    maplist(dif(H), T),
    all_diff(T).
```

So we can define our `set/2` as:

```
set(V, W) :-
    term_variables(V, VV),
    all_diff(VV),
    maplist(is, V, W).
```

The original `set/2` can thus be written as [**`maplist/3`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3) with [**`is/2`**](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(is)/2) as goal.

For example:

```
?- set([A,B,B], [1,2,2]).
A = 1,
B = 2.

?- set([A,B,C], [1,2,2]).
false.
```

If the second list contains only terms, and you do *not* want to evaluate expressions, we can - like @DanielLyons says - just use `V = W`:

```
set(V, W) :-
    term_variables(V, VV),
    all_diff(VV),
    V = W.
```

Since the unification algorithm will "*peal*" the functors, and thus eventually unfiy all elements in the left list with the values in the right list.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just do `V = W` instead of `maplist(is, V, W)`?

Comment: @DanielLyons: if there are expressions at the right side, then this will have some effect, and then it is equivalent with the original code, but yes, it is indeed shorter to use `V = W` instead.

Comment: @DanielLyons: updated with some extra explanations.

Comment: Is there a way of transforming the predicate set into a recursive one?

Comment: @Arashicage: [`maplist/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/apply.pl?show=src#maplist/2) is implemented in a recursive way [source](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/apply.pl?show=src#maplist/2).